# i need to add map .when i click country it will redirect to new activity

Tags: android

> i am creating app that layout has map ..when i click a country in map
>   it will redirect to new activity in the app ..is it possible can u
>   guide me please guide me i am fresher to the app development .. And
>   also need details about how to add a .gif image to splash screen by
>   webveiw

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/anim5.gif");
```

i am creating app that layout has map ..when i click a country in mapit will redirect to new activity in the app ..is it possible can u guide me please guide me i am fresher to the app development .. And also need details about how to add a .gif image to splash screen by webveiw
is it is a right procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to respond to map touch events:

```
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();

mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
             // Take action here - eg start activity
        }
});
```

Your other question seems completely unrelated, so it should be asked separately.